# Pi Zero freezes with using camera recording / motion detect programs

Tags: pi-zero-w, cpu, picamera

I am having problems with a wildlife cam project I am working on.

setup:
Pi Zero W
Stretch 2018-11-13
Pikrellcam with settings:
1024x768
12 fps
3,5 Mbitrate

However, the pi frequently freezes. 
I have tried different PSUs and cables
I have tried using fresh SD cards of good quality
I have disabled as much power hungry components as possible, e.g. hdmi etc

Now I found this post (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=212777) where they were running RPI cam interface and had similar problems and they changed the  config.txt and added:

over_voltage=4

force_turbo=1

The questions:
1. Does anyone have similar experiences with a similar setups as mine? Solutions?

**2. What exactly does the above change in the config.txt DO?**

I am currently trying this out but would like know more.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md all your overclocking information in one handy document

Comment: Be sure to add some kind of cooler on the board, to prevent it from overheating.

Comment: Thanks!  I am not at a level where I fully understand it all but I will continue reading, trying and searching. 
Yes, I do not expect to make the CPU work that hard so I just added a passive heatsink.

Comment: I got an good answer in this post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94410/what-happens-if-i-force-turbo-and-over-voltage-but-do-not-increase-arm-etc/94447#94447